# GtkApplicationWindow subclass "destroy" twice

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I took the application1 from examples in Gtk source
and modified GtkApplicationWindow subclass as to save some window state in the "destroy" signal handler. The problem with my code is that the `save_some_state()` is called twice. Why? How can I fix it?

```
static void
example_app_activate (GApplication *app) {

  ExampleAppWindow *win;

  win = example_app_window_new (EXAMPLE_APP (app));

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}

........

static void
on_app_window_destroy (GtkWidget* widget) 
{
    ExampleAppWindow* win = EXAMPLE_APP_WINDOW(widget);

    save_some_state(win);

    GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(example_app_window_parent_class)->destroy (widget);

}

static void
example_app_window_class_init (ExampleAppWindowClass *klass)
{
    GtkWidgetClass* widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass);

    widget_class->destroy = on_app_window_destroy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it definitely looks like you are destroying it twice by calling

```
GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(example_app_window_parent_class)->destroy (widget);
```

in the `on_app_window_destroy` callback

Comment: This is necessary, it chains up to the parent's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing example_app_window_parent_class? Is this derived from the widget? As GtkNerd says it may duplicate things if it is not chained right.

I am not entirely confident of the internals. For Gtk2, destroy is a GtkObject signal not a GtkWidget signal so you would cast as GTK_OBJECT_CLASS in that case, though that is likely irrelevant - For Gtk3 it is fine as is. I am not sure about the internals but the destroy signal might get called multiple times due to reference counting. A safer option is to override finalize as it should only get called the once irrespective.

Comment: No GTK_OBJECT_CLASS in GTK3.

Comment: updated. Fine as is in that regard for Gtk3, but note the documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-destroy) does say re: destroy "This signal is not suitable for saving widget state". finalise I believe is more suitable.

Comment: It's used in demo  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/application.c#L508.  Besides : https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/SaveWindowState

Comment: A `g_object_ref(win)` at the bottom of the `example_app_window_new()` seems to solve the problem. Why?